# iterating through multiple columns and appending data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

[image]

Input dataframe:

```html
dtf= {'A': ['00 12 3b 01 00 00 00 00','00 13 3b 01 00 00 00 00','00 14 3b 01 00 00 00 00'], 'B': ['59 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','60 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','61 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','62 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','64 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','65 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','66 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','67 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','69 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','70 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','71 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','72 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ','73 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f ']}
```

I have a data frame with columns A&B. I want to append for the values in column B with the values in column A such that the output should  look like this:

- 59 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 12 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  60 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 12 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  61 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 12 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  62 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 12 3b 01 00 00 00 00
- 64 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 13 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  65 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 13 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  66 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 13 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  67 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 13 3b 01 00 00 00 00
- 69 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 14 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  70 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 14 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  71 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 14 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  72 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 14 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  73 d0 7f 10 27 f8 7f ff 7f 00 14 3b 01 00 00 00 00

  This is a random sample but the **iterative loop** should work for th entire data. **I'm new to python and couldn't figure out any way(s) to do it.** The values in the dataframe are of `hex str` type. I'm expeccting the output in the form of a list.

Comment: please provide a reproducible input (as a DataFrame constructor, or csv file)

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is called 'df', you could do `df['B'].astype(str) + df['A'].astype(str)`

Comment: @mozway. i have added the snippet of dataframe. But I'm not sure how to present it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your dataframe looks **exactly** as it does in the screenshot.

You can forward fill the null values in column `A` and then concatenate the values from both columns. Since column `B` seems to be empty when `A` has a value, you can get rid of these rows to get the result in the bullet list.

```py
# Fill null values forward
df['A'] = df['A'].ffill()

# Concatenate `B` and `A`
df['new_col'] = df['B'].astype(str) + df['A'].astype(str)

# Get rid of rows where `B` is empty
df = df[df['B'].notna()]
```